# Duda en valores para una subconsulta SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mssql

Buenos días he estado trabajando recientemente con un filtrado de datos donde debo hacerlos por un ID especifico.

```sql
declare @clientesIdTable table (ID nvarchar(10));

insert into @clientesIdTable
select 
    ID
from 
    CLI_CLIENTES
where 
Ruc in (
    '171717171717001'
    ,'191919191919001'
)
```

con esto obtengo un resultado como lo siguinete:
`select * from @clientesIdTable`

produciendo lo siguiente:

| ID |
| --- |
| 000032 |
| 000052 |

y se me abrió la duda de si existe una mejor forma al momento de probar esta parte.

por ejemplo al declarar pasarle los valores que necesito directamente:

```sql
declare @clientesIdTable table (ID nvarchar(10)) = ['000032', '000052'];
```

y que produzca el mismo resultado `select * from @clientesIdTable`:

| ID |
| --- |
| 000032 |
| 000052 |

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda? Algo como lo que pones después sería más rápido, pero puede que dejes valores sin insertar si la tabla original cambia. Si es sólo para esos campos y de ciertos registros, ¿por qué no crear una vista en lugar de una tabla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí se pueden insertar los valores directamente, pero tienes que hacerlo de la misma forma en que lo harías con una tabla normal.

```
DECLARE @clientesIdTable TABLE(
    ID nvarchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO @clientesIdTable
VALUES( '171717171717001'),
      ( '191919191919001');
```

Puedes cambiar el código del `INSERT` por algo más tradicional

```
INSERT INTO @clientesIdTable
SELECT '171717171717001' UNION ALL
SELECT '191919191919001';
```

Sin embargo, al hacerlo como lo tenías antes, te aseguras que los valores existan en tu tabla de clientes. Eso ayuda a filtrar valores inválidos.

Comment: Sorry por esta duda pero existe alguna forma de asignación como en programación tipo array??? ej: `declare @clientesIdTable table (ID nvarchar(10)) = ['000032', '000052'];`?

Comment: En una tabla los valores no se asignan, se insertan. Por lo mismo, no existe nada como lo que describes. En ciertos RDBMS existen tipos de datos `array` que pueden ser asignados a columnas o utilizados como variables.

Comment: Listo. Gracias por la respuesta.